# Could not insert NULL value in to field (DateTime)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

I am struggling to solve this issue, despite there being many threads about it on SO.

I have a class that has a nullable `DateTime?` field like this:

```
public class ActiveItem
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> TimeStarted { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> LastHeard { get; set; }
}
```

I have a database schema defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ActiveItems] (
    [ID]          INT      IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [TimeStarted] DATETIME NULL,
    [LastHeard]   DATETIME NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ActiveWorkflows] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);
```

I then try to save an `ActiveItem` where `TimeStarted` and `LastHeard` are null.  However, when I try to do so I get the following error:

> "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'TimeStarted', table 'dbo.ActiveItems'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."

I can't seem to get around this.

The odd thing is that I can login to the SQL server and create a row in the table with null values.  Is this entity framework screwing up?

Comment: Where is the mapping kept and/or how do I update it?  I didn't realize some sort of mapping was kept.  Googling.....

Comment: Yes, I meant a EDMX file; =/

Comment: I don't seem to have an EDMX file or a `__MigrationHistory` table in my system tables

Comment: @StarPilot I don't have this issue with strings being null, for example.  Why would DateTime need a different/special null value?

Comment: Have you tried doing a trace on the database to see what the actual SQL being executed is, and to validate that it's hitting the correct database?

Comment: I'm still unclear from the comments if you are using model-first or code-first. Also, could you post the code where you're creating an instance of `ActiveItem` and saving it? Finally, StarPilot is incorrect, you should be able to write `foo.TimeStarted = null;` and have it persist correctly.

Comment: @CraigW. I am actually trying to do database first.  CJBS: trying to setup some tracing now.  Let me try to post some more code for help.

Comment: @CJBS I think you're correct... I'm hitting the wrong database.  I'm trying to do "database first" but it looks like entity framework is creating another database for me.

Comment: @CJBS: you are definitely correct.  If you create some sort of answer I will accept it.

Comment: May be you hitting wrong DB, etc. But for the future reference remember, if you use ADO.net to save [insert/update] value using SqlParameter and you need to save 'NULL' to DB - you need to set to `SqlParameter .Value = DbNull.Value`. SqlParameter will fail in you set value to `c# null`. Interestingly, Oracle ODP.Net `OracleParameter` can do both - `null` and `DbNull.Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that you're hitting the correct database, [do a SQL Trace](http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/ht/trace.htm) using Profiler.

It's likely if the constraint violation is inconsistent with what you expect (in terms of the schema) that you're hitting a different database.

Following that, update the connection string used to connect to Entity Framework to the correct database.